# Select element by next/previous button when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I'm trying to select tab elements by next/previous buttons instead of number buttons, means go to next tab by `click`.

*Default Buttons Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/LLdy3gd2/

**HTML**: *Default Number Buttons*

```
<p>
<button class="select-tab" value="0">1</button>
<button class="select-tab" value="1">2</button>
<button class="select-tab" value="2">3</button>
</p>
```

**JS**: *Default*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs({
 rotate: false,
 startCollapsed: 'accordion',
 collapsible: 'accordion',
 animation: 'slide',
 setHash: true,
 activate: function(e, tab) {
 $('.info').html('Tab <strong>' + tab.id + '</strong> activated!');
  },

activateState: function(e, state) {
//console.log(state);
$('.info').html('Switched from <strong>' + state.oldState + '</strong> state to <strong>' + state.newState + '</strong> state!');
}

});

$('#start-rotation').on('click', function() {
 $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('active');
});

$('.select-tab').on('click', function() {
 $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('activate', $(this).val());
});

});
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

*My New Buttons:*

**HTML:** *Instead of default buttons*

```
<div id="my-buttons">
<button class="select-tab">Next</button>
<button class="select-tab">Previous</button>
</div>
```

My **JS:** *I have added with Default JS*

```
$('#my-buttons').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.select-tab').toggle();
});
```

*Problem Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/LLdy3gd2/2/

How fix this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[epoch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30079053/417562) is getting there, but there's a little more that needs to be done, because you can also change tabs by clicking on them: we need to keep track of which tab is actually open, not which tab was the last clicked.

First I've added another class to your button:

```
<button class="select-tab next">Next</button>
```

Then I've added some code to track which the current tab is:

```
var activetab = -1;

$('#horizontalTab').on('tabs-activate', function(e, tab) {
   activetab = tab.id;
});
```

This listens for the `tabs-activate` event documented [here](https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs). It starts at `-1` so the first tab (index `0` will be the first to open if you click "next" immediately).

Then you need to modify the event listener a bit:

```
$('.select-tab').on('click', function () {
    var newtab;
    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
        newtab = (++activetab > 3 ? 0 : activetab);
    } else {
        newtab = (--activetab < 0 -1 ? 2 : activetab);
    }
    $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('activate', newtab);
});
```

This now checks which button was pressed. If we're going to the next tab, we increment the counter; if not, we decrement it. Then we instruct the plugin which tab to open.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLdy3gd2/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just increment/decrement based on the `Next`/`Previous` state:

```
$('.select-tab').on('click', function () {
    var size = $('#horizontalTab > ul > li').size();
    var nextPrevIndex = ($(this).text() === 'Next' ? ++i : --i) % size;

    $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('activate', nextPrevIndex);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLdy3gd2/5/

**EDIT**

*[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/LLdy3gd2/8/)* to support clicking of user seelction of tabs:

```
var i = 0;

$('#start-rotation').on('click', function () {
    $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('active');
});

$('#horizontalTab').on('tabs-activate', function(e, tab) {
   i = tab.id;
});

$('.select-tab').on('click', function () {
    var size = $('#horizontalTab > ul > li').size();
    var nextPrevIndex = ($(this).text() === 'Next' ? ++i : --i) % size;

    if (nextPrevIndex < 0) nextPrevIndex = (size - 1);
    if (nextPrevIndex > (size - 1)) nextPrevIndex = 0;

    console.log(nextPrevIndex);

    $('#horizontalTab').responsiveTabs('activate', nextPrevIndex);
});
```